# Java Virtual Machine Missing Aptana Studio

Tags: java, aptana

I am on windows 8.1 and i am trying to run Aptana studio 3

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: /C:/Users/Myname/Appdata/Roaming/Appcelerator/AptanaStudio/jre/bin/javaw.exe

Comment: Well, *IS* there any JVM at the location in question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows 10 x64 and was facing the same problem. I have JDK 7 (64-bit) installed on my machine and was still getting the error.

Solution was installing JRE x86 version even though my OS is 64 bit with JDK already installed.